# get last year week number using jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function($)
{    
$.getWeek = function(backWeekupTo){

Date.prototype.get_Week = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
}

var weekNumber = (new Date()).get_Week();

var dayNames = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var now = new Date();
var y = now.getFullYear();

weekrange = (y.toString() + "W" + (weekNumber-backWeekupTo));

return weekrange;
return this;
};

}(jQuery));

// and in controller 
var prevWk = $.getWeek(23);
```

I have written above code to get earlier week by passing parameter to it. But suppose in earlier month in current year this equation doesn't work it gives me negative value. 
Need solution to get proper week no. of last year..
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: May help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627783/how-to-calculate-the-total-weeks-in-a-year-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question right, the intent of your code is to return a string representing the week of the year, for a date N weeks in the past. Several things about this.

1. It's a bad idea to modify the prototype chain of common objects. Other libraries may overwrite with their own implementations or it may cause unexpected behavior in naive iterations over properties. Better to extract as a standalone utility function that takes the date as an argument.
2. You declare the `get_Week` function inside your jQuery plugin definition. That doesn't really make sense: you're now redefining `get_Week` every time you invoke `$.getWeek()`
3. Similarly, you are modifying jQuery's base object; you should be creating a plugin if you want to extend jQuery's functionality, by adding your function to `$.fn` (https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). But again, there's not really a need to do so. Since you aren't actually doing anything with jQuery, a standalone function will work just as well, and require less overhead.
4. You have two `return` statements in your function. The second one will never be executed, and I'm unclear why it's there to begin with. I suspect it's a typo, something left over from previous work?
5. You're making some heroic efforts to subtract the number of weeks by doing fancy millisecond math, but the `Date()` constructor will do all that for you simply by passing appropriate values:

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one
>   argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is
>   provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent
>   value will be adjusted. E.g. new Date(2013, 13, 1) is equivalent to
>   new Date(2014, 1, 1) -- *[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)*

6. Your "get week" implementation is nonstandard. Consider revising to return [ISO8601 weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601#Week_dates)
7. Various format and non-idiomatic JavaScript usages.

Make sure your final implementation includes lots of test cases. Date math is super easy to get wrong, and the code below isn't tested beyond what you see in the console logs.

```js
/* NOTES:
 * - All calculations are in local timezone. Consider revising to use UTC
 * - The "week" implementation is nonstandard. Consider revising to 
 *   return ISO8601 weeks: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601#Week_dates
 */

var ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

var getWeek = function(d) {
  var onejan = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  return Math.ceil((((d - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
};
console.log('week for 1-JAN-2015 should be `1`:', getWeek(new Date(2015, 0, 1)));
console.log('week for 30-JUN-2015 should be `27`:', getWeek(new Date(2015, 5, 30)));
console.log('FAIL: week for 2-JAN-2011 should be `52` (52nd week of 2010):', getWeek(new Date(2011, 0, 2)));

var subtractWeeks = function(weeks) {
  var weeksAsDays = weeks * 7;
  var today = new Date();
  var pastWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - weeksAsDays);
  return pastWeek;
};
console.log('1 week ago as of 30-JUN-2015 should be `23-JUN-2015`:', subtractWeeks(1));
console.log('27 weeks ago as of 30-JUN-2015 should be `23-JUN-2015`:', subtractWeeks(27));
console.log('52 weeks ago as of 30-JUN-2015 should be `23-JUN-2015`:', subtractWeeks(52));


var getWeekRange = function(d){
  var weekNumber = getWeek(d);
  var y = d.getFullYear();
  var weekrange = (y.toString() + "W" + weekNumber);
  return weekrange;
};
console.log('week range for 1-JAN-2015 should be `2015W1`:', getWeekRange(new Date(2015, 0, 1)));
console.log('week range for 30-JUN-2015 should be `2015W27`:', getWeekRange(new Date(2015, 5, 30)));


var getPastWeekRange = function(weeksInPast) {
  var pastDate = subtractWeeks(weeksInPast);
  return getWeekRange(pastDate);
};
console.log('past week range for 1 week ago, as of 30-JUN-2015 should be `2015W26`:', getPastWeekRange(1));
console.log('past week range for 23 weeks ago, as of 30-JUN-2015 should be `2015W4`:', getPastWeekRange(23));
console.log('past week range for 52 weeks ago, as of 30-JUN-2015 should be `2014W27`:', getPastWeekRange(52));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried with above code with this bin ..https://jsbin.com/popezafewu/edit?html,js,console,output.  But because of some some [object object]  i tried JSON.stringify to resolved that but again it gives me ""\"2014-12-30T18:30:00.000Z\"" kind of console. can i get "2014W27" format using substract function?